# If I try browsing the fqdn of my jenkins server, my browser times out, but the domain resolves in the commandline, and I can browse the ip address

Tags: domain, jenkins

I have a jenkins server in aws. I can browse it (on my private network) by visiting http://{ip-of-my-jenkins-server}:8080, but if I try browsing http://{fqdn-of-my-jenkins-server}:8080, the request times out.

If I open a commandline and type hostname {fqdn-of-my-jenkins-server}, I get an ip, but if I try curling it, that times out also. But if I curl the ip, I get html back.

I don't understand why this is happening; it doesn't make any sense.

The domain is set up on a windows domain server on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had the previous IP of my jenkins server in my personal hosts file - this was  relic from some earlier network tests I ran on my computer a couple years back. Clearing out those host entries solved the problem.